# Where to find Microsoft.VisualStudio.RegDetour assembly?

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-sdk

I'm using NuGet package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Settings.15.0/15.0.25824-RC

When I try to load Visual Studio 2017 RC settings via [`ExternalSettingsManager.CreateForApplication(devenvPath);`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.settings.externalsettingsmanager.aspx) an exception is thrown:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.RegDetour, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Where can I find this assembly?

Comment: Crystal ball says that you did not *really* mean to use a package for the VS2017 release candidate.  The version number of VS2015 is 14.0

Comment: I don't have an URL to MSDN for VS 2017 class version, but use this class for reading VS 2017 RC settings. Updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it at opendll.com site: http://www.opendll.com/index.php?file-download=microsoft.visualstudio.regdetour.dll&arch=32bit&version=15.0.26009.0&dsc=Visual%20Studio%20Registry%20Detour%20DLL#